# Example of a differentiable $f$ and $(x^*,y^*)$ where $x^*=\arg\min_x f(x,y^*)$, $y^*=\arg\min_y f(x^*,y)$, yet $(x^*,y^*)\neq \arg\min_{x,y}f(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

More generally, could there be a point $x^*=(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)$ that minimizes a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ along each coordinate, i.e., $x_i^*=\arg\min_{x_i} f(x_1^*,...,x_{i-1}^*, x_i, x_{i+1}^*,...,x_n^*)$ (note this is a stronger condition than $x^*$ being stationary) , yet $x^*$ isn't the global minimum?

I suspect the answer is yes, but I'm having trouble coming up with a proof or example.

Comment: Does $x^4+y^4-4x^2y^2$ with $x^*=y^*=0$ do what you want, or is there an additional constraint on $(x^*,y^*)$?

Comment: It's a little weird that the definition of $x^*$ and $y^*$ seems to be circular, in that one depends on the other.

Comment: @Chappers I suppose that would work...what I initially had in mind is that a global minimum of $f$ should actually exist (so that $f$ is bounded below). I've tweaked the title a little to reflect this.